# lazarus identifier expected but PROCEDURE found

Tags: lazarus

I am trying to install Webkit 0.5 into Lazarus.

But when I try to compile I'm getting this error:

lazarus identifier expected but PROCEDURE found

```
Fatal: Syntax error, "identifier" expected but "PROCEDURE" found
```

The code it stops at is:

```
implementation
uses
  //LazWebKit
{$IFDEF LCLGTK2}
  Gtk2WSLazWebkitSettings;
{$ENDIF} //stops here

procedure RegisterWebkitSettings;
begin
{$IFDEF LCLGTK2}
  RegisterWSComponent(TCustomWebkitSettings, TGtk2WebkitSettings);
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case you have to include the `uses` keyword into your `{$IFDEF}` as well. If its directive is not defined, the produced code looks like this (notice the orphaned `uses` keyword):

```
...
implementation

uses

procedure RegisterWebkitSettings;
begin

end;
```

So to fix this problem use this instead:

```
{$IFDEF LCLGTK2}
uses
  Gtk2WSLazWebkitSettings;
{$ENDIF}
```

Besides, if the `RegisterWebkitSettings` used in your code is valid only if that `LCLGTK2` directive is defined, wrap also the procedure into an `{$IFDEF}`, like:

```
{$IFDEF LCLGTK2}
procedure RegisterWebkitSettings;
begin
  RegisterWSComponent(TCustomWebkitSettings, TGtk2WebkitSettings);
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Strange. More errors seem to appear after that one's fixed. I'm just trying to install: http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazwebkit/?source=typ_redirect version 0.5. Can't understand why I can't compile it :o/

Comment: I'm also using the latest version of Lazarus. My os is Windows 7.

Comment: The code quotes never worked for windows, since there LCL_GTK2 is typically not defined.

Comment: Way too many errors to install it. Can't believe other people haven't posted the issue. Might have to look for another browser for Lazarus :o/

Comment: I never tried LazWebkit, but the note on the project's page *Currently is only implemented for GTK2 widgetset.* sounds like you're out of luck on Windows platform.